# Backbone reload slider when view changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I have a view that is inside a "Royal Slider" slideshow, the royal slider wraps the divs inside like this

```
<div id="myView" class="royalSlider rsDefault"></div>
```

That is the root element for my view, I have a list of items that gets appended to that root element. Royal slider when initialized `$('.royalSlider').royalslider(function() {})` will wrap each of those elements intelligently and create a nice slide effect (I am using it as sideways scrolling on the x axis no so much as a slider);

When I click to re render the view I empty the HTML then add the new content, how do I re-initialize the royal slider to again intelligently wrap the new elements?

Does that make sense, I can provide more code for my view, but I am just really not sure what I need to do here.

I'm not 100% sure how to re-render but I made the royalSlider as a function

```
royalSliderReload = function() {
    var rsi = $('.royalSlider').royalSlider({
            keyboardNavEnabled: true,
            autoScaleSlider: true,
            autoScaleSliderWidth:  1400,
            autoScaleSliderHeight: 600,
            sliderDrag:  false,
            navigateByClick: false,
            addActiveClass:  true
    });
}
```

I try calling `royalSliderReload();` inside my render method on the view then that didn't work so I tried in the initialize method no no success. I also tried creating it as a method inside the view then when re-rendering and calling `this.royalSlider();`

Comment: please also specify your rerender code

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't give a lot of info about the plug-in... Anyway, as stated in RoyalSlider's documentation (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/documentation/#api), if you modify DOM you have to destroy your RoyalSlider instance like this :

```
var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');
slider.destroy();
```

Then you can add news slides to your slider

```
slider.appendSlide($(".element"));
```

This method probably works if you remove only you slider contents, not the slider itself.

Comment: Oh thanks, I actually seen that awhile back but didn't think to hard on it, so let me see what I can do.

Comment: Actually destroy() doesn't remove slider instance, but removes all events and clears all slider data. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: No worries, looks like I can only use `var slider = $(".royalSlider").data('royalSlider');` inside a `$(document).ready()` function stated on a forum thread post, I verified and its true the that code returns undefined unless inside a ready func.

Comment: Whoops maybe I am looking at it wrong, instead of doing it the traditional way `$('.royalSlider').royalSlider({})` I should write the above and destroy/append when appropriate?

Comment: Well... All your code should be wrapped on a document.ready() function. So, you must initialize royalSlider() at beginning, and then you can play with destroy, append,etc... as much as you remove/append contents inside your slider.

Comment: Im really confused why `slider` keeps coming up undefined, I did wrap my code in `document.ready()` I initialized royalSlider(), then I try to destroy on click event, and keep getting `slider` is undefined?

Comment: it only works if I set it in a timeout function 300ms